# Disable toast when screen is pinned in Android

Tags: security

When passing my phone to someone, I pin the screen for safety reasons. Is there a way to disable those ugly toasts which keep popping up and giving them a gist of what's happening?

Answer (score 4):

You can setup [adb](/questions/tagged/adb) and issue this command:

```
adb shell appops set android TOAST_WINDOW deny
```

You won't be having that toast anymore. However, this has the side effect of not being shown any toast that Android package would have displayed, so keep this under consideration.

You can replace `deny` with `allow` to revert the changes.